# gedit highlighting " CISCO IOS" can't find one

Tags: gedit, cisco, syntax-highlighting

daily i 'm using gedit in order to configure Cisco devices

is there someone who created a cisco highlighting language   ???
can't find one .... and it is a loooong way creating one from scratch....

Answer (score 0):

GEdit uses [GtkSourceView](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView) for its syntax highlighting.
[Language File](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=508061) for IOS based devices.
[Language File](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=508062) for PIX/ASA based devices.

Comment: yeah ,.-........ i gave a look to :/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs  but there's no trace of an IOS-like syntax scheme